# Built in double-asterisk power function not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x

This prints -2.4:

```
print(-3**0.8)
```

But this prints an imaginary number...?

```
a = -3
b = 0.8
print(a**b)
```

I can't figure out what is causing this and this problem is breaking my program. How do you make it so that the second statement outputs the same as the first in a general case that works for positive and negative values for `a`?

Answer (score 6):

Per [the Python 3.6 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator):

> ### 6.5. The power operator
>
> The power operator binds more tightly than unary operators on its left; it binds less tightly than unary operators on its right. The syntax is:
>
> ```
> power ::=  ( await_expr | primary ) ["**" u_expr]
> ```
>
> Thus, in an unparenthesized sequence of power and unary operators, the operators are evaluated from right to left (this does not constrain the evaluation order for the operands): `-1**2` results in `-1`.

Thus, in the first example:

```
>>> -3 ** 0.8
-2.4082246852806923
```

It's evaluated *right to left* as `**` has higher precedence than unary `-`, binding tighter -- so here, `3 ** 0.8` is evaluated first, then the unary `-` operator is applied for a negative value. In the second example however, the expression is equivalent `(-3) ** 0.8` as `-3` is stored in a name, and evaluation results is an imaginary number:

```
>>> a = -3
>>> b = 0.8
>>> a ** b
(-1.9482946966653392+1.4155189542146738j)
```

A solution would be to calculate the result without unary operators, *then applying a sign as necessary*, per [Shakar Bhattarai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44992633/5647260):

```
>>> int(a / abs(a)) * (abs(a) ** b)
-2.4082246852806923
```

The first part, `int(a / abs(a))` evaluates to either `-1.0` or `1.0` depending on if `a` is negative or not, basically applying the sign. It then multiplies that by the result of `a ** b` regardless of `a`'s sign. That will first compute `a ** b` disregarding it's sign, then applying the sign as necessary. This will get rid of the discrepancy. You could apply the same concept with [`math.copysign`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/math.html#math.copysign):

```
>>> math.copysign(1, a) * (abs(a) ** b)
-2.4082246852806923
```

This will just copy the sign from `a` to `1`, which will give `-1.0` or `1.0` based on negativity.

Answer (score 3):

This is because of the precedence of the power operator. The power operator binds tighter than unary operators. So:

```
-3 ** 0.8
```

is evaluated as

```
-(3 * 0.8)
```

You can see how Python parses your code using the `ast` module:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse('-3 ** 0.8'))
'Module(body=[Expr(value=UnaryOp(op=USub(), operand=BinOp(left=Num(n=3), op=Pow(), right=Num(n=0.8))))])'
>>>
```

In the above, the `3 ** 0.8` is treated as one expression with `**` being the operator. The unary minus is then applied to the value of the inner expression.

However, in your second example the values are stored in variables, so the precedence does not affect the expression. So `a ** b` is equivlent to `(-3) ** 0.8`

The solution is to bind the unary minus to the three using parenthesis:

```
>>> (-3) ** 0.8
(-1.94829469666534+1.4155189542146727j)
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

The ** operator has the highest precedence over all other operators. Hence when you use

```
print(-3**0.8)
```

python first evaluates the exponential and then negates it.

But when you run

```
a = -3
b = 0.8
print(a**b)
```

a has implicitly been negated first. Hence the result is effectively a imaginary number (a negative number raised to a fractional exponent)

To solve your issue, you could do something like

```
 print (int(a/abs(a))*(abs(a)**b))
```